# HTML 5 canvas causes browser to lag when switching tabs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

This is my current code:
http://animus.site44.com/
(Press the blue button in the top left)

It doesn't happen all the time but every so often (generally while listening to pandora.com) the code will freeze the browser when switching tabs. It only last a second or two but it is very annoying. The code tends to be very smooth when no tabs are being transversed.

I know making a site using only canvas is a bit odd, but I was wondering if it was possible to make this code work without the lag.

Comment: Examinining your whole site could be a big effort.  Instead, please reduce your code to a smaller snippet that reproduces your unexpected delay.

Comment: I am not quite sure where the lag is comming in, but the file main.js is the only file that runs all of the other .js files are data storage and class declarations. I think the problem might be from the redraw of the screen. The problem might also come from using setInterval and request animation frame. I use setInterval for the animation ticks and request animation frame for drawing. I am currently in a class so I cannot cut the code right now but the GUI js file is just datastructures.

Comment: @user3006377 There is your hypothesis. Now you just have to try to prove or disprove it.

Answer (score 0):

So oddly the lag was caused because of requestAnimationFrame(). I switched out requestAnimationFrame for setInterval() and the lag was completely removed. I am guessing it is because I lowered the framerate to 30 (setInterval(draw, 1000/30);) and it didn't have to draw as fast.

Answer (score 0):

requestAnimationFrame is advised because it is tidier: requestAnimationFrame switches off when the current browser is tabbed away. Perhaps this is something to do with the lag? setInterval will only stop calling the update method if you call clearInterval or the browser is closed. Currently I have 9 windows open in my browser, if half of them were using setInterval my computer would feel it.

The link has been changed so I couldn't reproduce the lag issue.